# How to restrict AMI user to see EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

I want to make an account to external consultant to help us with AWS, but I want to allow him to only see certain EC2 instances instead of all.

I've read AWS documents/blogs about AMI and policies setting. I'm aware "describe" action [can not have resource level permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/demystifying-ec2-resource-level-permissions/).

Is there any workaround to this? or we really need to let external consultant see all the instances' information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is currently not possible as many EC2 actions do not support resource-level permissions. check the answer to [this question](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/restrict-ec2-iam/) on their knowledge center site, and here I am quoting.

> This is not currently possible for all API actions within EC2, but it is for some. Many essential EC2 actions [do not support resource-level permissions or conditions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions), and isolating IAM users or groups of users’ access to EC2 resources by any criteria other than AWS region does not fit most use cases

Comment: many many thanks! I googled for 2 hrs but seems like I still missed that article. (y)